# Why is my constructor not inheriting the methods of the super constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, constructor, prototype

This is my first question so I may not be doing things properly. I am trying to learn JS and Node JS. I am struggling with the util.inherits function.

I can't seem to understand why the properties and methods of the Human constructor aren't available to an instance of a Male even though I have used the `util.inherits` function. `james instance of Human` comes back true so surely the `james` object should have access to the `Human` methods.

I understand that `util.inherits` use is now discouraged but want to understand why it's not working to further my understanding.

```
var util = require('util');

function Human (){
    this.firstName = 'James';
    this.secondName = 'Michael';
    this.age = 8;
    this.humanFunction = function(){
        console.log('I am a human');
    }
}

function Male (){
    this.gender = 'male';
    this.power = 5;
    this.who = function(){
        return 'I am Male';
    };
}

util.inherits(Male, Human)

let james = new Male();

console.log(james instanceof Human); //true
console.log(james.firstName); //undefined
james.humanFunction(); //james.humanFunction is not a function
```

Comment: Question: why are you using a package called `util` instead of just using JavaScript classes, which can do this automatically?

Comment: Add `Human.call(this);` to the first line of your `Male` constructor.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm aware of classes and know they do this function already. Only asking as clearly there is a flaw in my understanding here so even if I could (and should in fact) do this using classes I want to understand why it's not working using the util.inherits.

Comment: The reason is because inherits only copies properties from Human.prototype to Male.prototype, any instance properties (defined using the this keyword) are not automatically inherited. To do this, you have to call the super constructor with Human.call(this);

Comment: @4castle Great, this works. Any idea were I should look to understand why I need to do this?

Comment: For a better understanding, google prototypical inheritance in JavaScript.

Comment: @TanvirulIslam no, you don't: Node.js [explicitly tells you to please not use it](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) in its own documentation. It was a poor implementation of something that has been doable with real JS (even ES5) for years now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was aware of Node.js saying that. But I see what you mean. I'll use the code you've written below instead. Thanks

Comment: @Eladian Ohhhhhhh. Now I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's 2017, and Node.js [tells you not to use this](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor). Instead, use real class notation:

```
// our initial class
class Human {
  constructor(first, second, age) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.secondName = second;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = 'unspecified'
  }

  sayWhat() {
    console.log(`I am a human, and my gender is ${this.gender}`);
  }
}

// our 'Male' class, a subclass of Human:
class Male extends Human {
  constructor(first, second, age) {
    super(first, second, age)
    this.gender = 'male';
  }
}
```

And then we call the same code, but with string templating because that's a thing modern versions of Node do:

```
let james = new Male('james', 'michael', 8);
console.log(`is james a human?: ${james instanceof Human}`);
console.log(`james's first name is: ${james.firstName}`);
console.log(`james says: ${james.sayWhat()}`);
```

Comment: Although an alternative method to achieving the same thing. This does not answer the question the OP is trying to get answered. He wanted an understanding of why his code was not working. Simply providing an alternative and not explaining why his code does not work does nothing help better his or potential visitors to this questions understanding. He will come across code that is still using pre-2017 methods of achieving inheritance. Assuming he continues down the JavaScript road, how will your answer help him then?

Comment: And future visitors with this same question with also learn not to use this pattern anymore, because it's a *bad pattern and should no longer be used*. Anyone who continues with JavaScript is most certainly better off learning what to do in modern JS.

Comment: @Eladian This is true. I do actually understand why the code didn't work now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What if I come across it in other older code?

Comment: 'Bad pattern' is subjective, the class based approach is just sugar coating prototypical inheritance. For this reason, prototypical inheritance is _still important to understand_.

Comment: And in this case, where the code is for Node.js, and Node.js says to not use this pattern anymore, we have an objective authority. As for "what if I encounter this in older code": if you encounter this in older code, that code wasn't working back when it was written, so for real world examples I struggle to see a genuine situation in which this will crop up. This specific one looks very much like you writing new code, not encountering old code. That said, if you just want to know "how to do inheritance in ES5", google has loads of excellent writeups on that (including by Crockford etc.)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans What I meant by what if I encounter it in old code is not if that old code has the same issue. What I mean is what if the old code uses util.inherits. Having only begun to learn JS very recently I learnt from the beginning to use classes. However, I then learnt that classes were syntactical sugar and so wanted to understand prototypical inheritance better. I came across this problem when trying to understand a Node Js tutorial (written before ES6 of course) and out of curiosity wanted to understand why what I was trying to do wasn't working .

Comment: @TanvirulIslam that is the perfect approach when learning new languages. Continue to be curious and understand the deeper working of things and ask questions, do not just settle for knowing just the alternatives. You will be a better coder for it. Another point to make is that it is fairly likely you will come across prototypical inheritance when working on JavaScript within a browser environment also, so it is definitely good to know one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

please add Human.call(this); in Male() function

var util = require('util');

```
function Human (){
    this.firstName = 'James';
    this.secondName = 'Michael';
    this.age = 8;
    this.humanFunction = function(){
        console.log('I am a human');
    }
}

function Male (){
    this.gender = 'male';
    this.power = 5;
    this.who = function(){
        return 'I am Male';
    };
    Human.call(this);
}

util.inherits(Male, Human)

let james = new Male();

console.log(james instanceof Human); //true
console.log(james.firstName); //undefined
james.humanFunction(); //james.humanFunction is not a function
```